# Why "Please fill out this field" validate message show when I clicked Irrelevant button

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, required

I used map on my page and when I clicked 'cellSize' button Fill the fields warning appeared. I dont want to this. How can fix this ?

Warning like this : [image]

this is my text field :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input ng-model="Name" ng-readonly="view.readonly" ng-maxlength="100" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="cluster-name" placeholder="Name" required>
</div>
```

and this is my increment button click :

```
change: function () {
    this.trigger("spin");

    $scope.cellSizeCoefficient = this.value();
    $scope.$broadcast('mapCellSizeChanged', $scope.map);

    $.each($scope.cellShapes, function (index, cellShape) {
        var radius = getRadius(cellShape.Cell);
        cellShape.Circle.setRadius(radius);
        if (cellShape.Circle.label) {
            var labelLoc = findLocationAtDistanceFrom(cellShape.Cell.LOC, cellShape.Cell.AZ, radius);
            cellShape.Circle.label.setLatLng([labelLoc.Y, labelLoc.X]);
        }
    });
    if (selectedCellCircle) {
        var radius = getRadius(selectedCellCircle.Cell) + 50;
        selectedCellCircle.setRadius(radius);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're seeing the message due to the `required` attribute on the `input` element. It's shown when the form is submit, so I'm guessing you need to put `type="button"` on your 'increment button'

Comment: I used kendo button and my button code like this : 
`'<button style="margin-left:2px;" kendo-button="btnCellSizeIncrement" k-options="btnCellSizeIncrementOptions"><i class="fa fa-plus pi-icon pi-icon-plus"></i></button>'`
. Any idea @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Yeah, you need to add `type="button` to that to solve the problem. I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing the message due to the `required` attribute on the input element. It's shown when the `form` is submit which is happening when the 'increment' button is clicked.

To stop that behaviour add a `type="button"` attribute to the `button`:

```
<button type="button" style="margin-left:2px;" kendo-button="btnCellSizeIncrement" k-options="btnCellSizeIncrementOptions">
  <i class="fa fa-plus pi-icon pi-icon-plus"></i>
</button>
```

Just FYI, you should add the `type="button"` attribute on any `button` elements that you *do not* want to submit the `form` when they are clicked.

Comment: Thank you very much @RoryMcCrossan. (by the way I am a girl (not he, she :) ))

Comment: Glad to help. Apologies if I implied you were a man somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `required` attribute from this HTML if its not a required field , otherwise browser will show this message on form submit. Make sure you are not submitting the form while clicking on the cell size button.

```
<input ng-model="Name" ng-readonly="view.readonly" ng-maxlength="100" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="cluster-name" placeholder="Name" required>
```

Comment: Having a `required` attribute on the `input` is a perfectly normal thing to do. The issue that needs solving is why is it appearing when the 'increment' button is clicked

Comment: I think he wants to keep the field required, but removing the message, I might have not understand

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan as i said may be a form is getting submitted, so he needs to make it a `button ` and not `<input type=submit>`

Comment: If you come to text in, I want to see this message but I do not want to see this message if I click on the increment button. If I add 'novalidate' I never see the warning message. I used kendo for my button. my button code like this :
 `'<button style="margin-left:2px;" kendo-button="btnCellSizeIncrement" k-options="btnCellSizeIncrementOptions"><i class="fa fa-plus pi-icon pi-icon-plus"></i></button>'` @Niladri @Minirock @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 0):

Add `novalidate` with form tag as it's required property so that will trigger HTML5 validation.

```
<form novalidate>
<div class="form-group"> <label for="name">Name</label> <input ng-model="Name" ng-readonly="view.readonly" ng-maxlength="100" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="cluster-name" placeholder="Name" required> </div>
</form>
```

Comment: If you come to text in, I want to see this message but I do not want to see this message if I click on the increment button. If I add 'novalidate' I never see the warning message. @HaRdikKaji

Answer (score 0):

I had a button that was causing this same behaviour, triggering the form validation when I didn't want it. My button swapped some form fields. The solution was easy though: instead of defining the button as an input element with an onclick event I just changed it to an img element with an onclick event. The button acts on the form, it isn't part of the form which I think is the same as yours.